# Implementing HTTP or HTTPS depending on page

Tags: security, http, ssl, https

I want to implement https on only a selection of my web-pages. I have purchased my SSL certificates etc and got them working.  Despite this, due to speed demands i cannot afford to place them on every single page.

Instead i want my server to serve up http or https depending on the page being viewed. An example where this has been done is ‘99designs’

The problem in slightly more detail:

1. When my visitors first visit my site they only have access to non-sensitive information and therefore i want them to be presented with simple http.
2. Then once they login they are granted access to more sensitive information, e.g. profile information for which HTTPS is used to deliver.
3. Despite being logged in, if the user goes back to a non-sensitive page such as the homepage then i want it delivered using HTTP.

One common solution seems to be using the .htaccess file. The problem is that my site is relatively large meaning that to use this would require me to write a rule for every page (several hundred) to determine whether it should be server up using http or https. 
And then there is the problem of defining user generated content pages.

Please help,

Many thanks,

David

Comment: Couldn't use just partition your site? E.g. `http://www.example.com` and `https://members.example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

You've not mentioned anything about the architecture you are using. Assuming that the SSL termination is on the webserver, then you should set up separate virtual hosts with **completely seperate and non-overlapping** document trees, and for preference, use a path schema which does not overlap (to avoid little accidents).